# Complex joins with counts not dependent on all tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have 8 tables I am joining in order to run a rather complex report, and am hitting a wall due to the database structure and my limited knowledge of multiple joins. The relevant portion of the structure is:

[image: DB Schema Dia]

The report I need to generate will look like the following:

[image: DB Report Ex]

So far my attempts have all involved `LEFT JOIN`s from Table1 to each of Tables 2-6, a `LEFT JOIN` from Table 7 to Table 6, and a `LEFT JOIN` from Table 8 to Table 7. I've also tried `INNER JOIN`s with Tables 6-8. I've tried `COUNT(DISTINCT Table1ID)` for the relevant tables, as well as `SUM(CASE WHEN x THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` in each case, all `GROUP BY Table8Val`.

In every attempt, my numbers are WAY too high. In some cases, they're off by a few thousand, and in other cases they're hundreds of thousands. How should I join these tables so that I may test against each table independent of most other tables?

### *EDIT*

Here is the latest query I've tried. Field/table names have been changed to protect the innocent.

```sql
SELECT  t8.T8val
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT t1.pkT1id)  AS [Main]
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT t2.fkT1id)  AS [Has t2 vals]
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT t3.fkT1id)  AS [Has t3 vals]
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT t4.fkT1id)  AS [Has t4 vals]
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT t5.fkT1id)  AS [Has t5 vals]        

FROM            Table8  t8  (NOLOCK)        
    JOIN        Table7  t7  (NOLOCK)    ON  t8.pkT8id = t7.fkT8id
    JOIN        Table6  t6  (NOLOCK)    ON  t7.pkT7id = t6.fkT7id
    LEFT JOIN   Table1  t1  (NOLOCK)    ON  t1.pkT1id = t6.fkT1id
    LEFT JOIN   Table2  t2  (NOLOCK)    ON  t1.pkT1id = t2.fkT1id                            
    LEFT JOIN   Table3  t3  (NOLOCK)    ON  t1.pkT1id = t3.fkT1id                            
    LEFT JOIN   Table4  t4  (NOLOCK)    ON  t1.pkT1id = t4.fkT1id   
    LEFT JOIN   Table5  t5  (NOLOCK)    ON  t1.pkT1id = t5.fkT1id                            

WHERE
    t8.T8val IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY T8.t8val
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

### *Edit 2*

Here's [a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39519) of an example of the schema. The desired output would be [image: desired output]

Comment: A left join will return all values from the "left" table and NULL for the values in the right table that do not match.  I'm guessing that you are using left joins where an inner join would be more apropriate expecially since you have FK's in almost every table.

Comment: However, don't INNER JOINs pare down the result set, making order important? For instance, if record 2 appears in table 2 and 3, but record 3 appears in table 3 but not 2, INNER JOINing Tables 1 and 2, followed by 1 and 3 would be missing record 3 because it was not present in 2. Or, is my understanding flawed?

Comment: @jbarker2160 I tried using INNER JOINs instead of left joins, and the first two columns returned the same result which should not happen.

Comment: @Andy Any chance you can edit your post with some sample data and the desired final result or create a sql fiddle with the data? It'd be easier to debug if we could see some data.

Comment: @bluefeet Okay, created a SQLFiddle and added expected results. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot do this with your current schema. Once you get to table 6 (which is a many-to-many joiner table), your results go haywire. You cannot get the count for each Table8Val for anything but your table7 values.

Comment: This is easy to see once you realize the "foo" value in table 8 relates to table1Id of 3,6,8,9.  This makes any joins to other tables past that point a multiple of 4, for just this one ID.  You could try to do some math but since you have no guarantee that the other table will have each Table1ID (left/right join), your math COULD be wrong.

Comment: @Steve I can guarantee 100% that once the schema is fully implemented, each table listed with a foreign key to T1 will have many. However, I'm guessing that doesn't affect my situation any. Is it possible to do if I group the values from Tables 2-5 in individual queries?

Comment: @Andy see my answere below looks like you were just missing the outer joins.

Comment: my god, it's full of `NOLOCK`

Comment: [Bad habits : Using `NOLOCK` everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: @AaronBertrand thank you for bringing that to my attention! All of my knowledge of SQL is self-taught and has come from workplace necessity. Pre-acquisition, it was my company's policy to use NOLOCK for anything that does not explicitly alter the database. I'm going to read up on this some more and see if it should be brought to anyone's attention.

Comment: @Andy `NOLOCK` is usually magic pixie-dust and it doesn't even do what its name implies (it can prevent some blocking, but it absolutely still takes locks). Usually people use it because it's a "quick fix" that seems to speed up queries, but they aren't aware of all the nasty side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats happening is you are creating a cartesian product of your result set. This can lead to devastating performance as well as inaccurate result sets. I've broken the query down to all of its parts and then joined all the parts together to obtain the desired result set.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2c0b1/8

```
with Main
as (
    select t8.Table8Val,
        t6.fkTable1ID
    from Table8 t8(nolock)
    inner join Table7 t7(nolock) on t8.pkTable8ID = t7.fkTable8ID
    inner join Table6 t6(nolock) on t7.pkTable7ID = t6.fkTable7ID
    ),
T2
as (
    select t.fkTable1ID,
        count(*) count_
    from Table2 t
    group by t.fkTable1ID
    ),
T3
as (
    select t.fkTable1ID,
        t.typeId,
        count(*) count_
    from Table3 t
    group by t.fkTable1ID,
        t.typeId
    ),
T4
as (
    select t.fkTable1ID,
        count(*) count_
    from Table4 t
    group by t.fkTable1ID
    ),
T5
as (
    select t.fkTable1ID,
        count(*) count_
    from Table5 t
    group by t.fkTable1ID
    )
select m.Table8Val,
    m.fkTable1ID,
    t2_.count_ Table2Count,
    (
        select t3_.count_
        from T3 t3_
        where t3_.fkTable1ID = m.fkTable1ID
            and t3_.typeId = 1
        ) Table3Type1Count,
    (
        select t3_.count_
        from T3 t3_
        where t3_.fkTable1ID = m.fkTable1ID
            and t3_.typeId = 2
        ) Table3Type2Count,
    (
        select t3_.count_
        from T3 t3_
        where t3_.fkTable1ID = m.fkTable1ID
            and t3_.typeId = 3
        ) Table3Type3Count,
    t4_.count_ Table4Count,
    t5_.count_ Table5Count
from Main m
left join T2 t2_ on t2_.fkTable1ID = m.fkTable1ID
left join T4 t4_ on t4_.fkTable1ID = m.fkTable1ID
left join T5 t5_ on t5_.fkTable1ID = m.fkTable1ID;
```

There is also this result set that differs from your original question.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2c0b1/7

```
with Main
as (
    select t8.Table8Val,
        t8.pkTable8ID,
         t6.fkTable1ID
    from Table8 t8(nolock)
    inner join Table7 t7(nolock) on t8.pkTable8ID = t7.fkTable8ID
    inner join Table6 t6(nolock) on t7.pkTable7ID = t6.fkTable7ID
    ),
T2
as (
    select t.fkTable1ID,
        count(*) count_
    from Table2 t
    group by t.fkTable1ID
    ),
T3
as (
    select t.fkTable1ID,
        t.typeId,
        count(*) count_
    from Table3 t
    group by t.fkTable1ID,
        t.typeId
    ),
T4
as (
    select t.fkTable1ID,
        count(*) count_
    from Table4 t
    group by t.fkTable1ID
    ),
T5
as (
    select t.fkTable1ID,
        count(*) count_
    from Table5 t
    group by t.fkTable1ID
    )
select result1.pkTable8ID,
    result1.Table8Val,
     count(*) Table1Count,
    sum(result1.Table2Count) Table2Count,
    sum(result1.Table3Type1Count) Table3Type1Count,
    sum(result1.Table3Type2Count) Table3Type2Count,
    sum(result1.Table3Type3Count) Table3Type3Count,
    sum(result1.Table4Count) Table4Count,
    sum(result1.Table5Count) Table5Count
from (
    select m.Table8Val,
        m.pkTable8ID,
        m.fkTable1ID,
        t2_.count_ Table2Count,
        (
            select t3_.count_
            from T3 t3_
            where t3_.fkTable1ID = m.fkTable1ID
                and t3_.typeId = 1
            ) Table3Type1Count,
        (
            select t3_.count_
            from T3 t3_
            where t3_.fkTable1ID = m.fkTable1ID
                and t3_.typeId = 2
            ) Table3Type2Count,
        (
            select t3_.count_
            from T3 t3_
            where t3_.fkTable1ID = m.fkTable1ID
                and t3_.typeId = 3
            ) Table3Type3Count,
        t4_.count_ Table4Count,
        t5_.count_ Table5Count
    from Main m
    left join T2 t2_ on t2_.fkTable1ID = m.fkTable1ID
    left join T4 t4_ on t4_.fkTable1ID = m.fkTable1ID
    left join T5 t5_ on t5_.fkTable1ID = m.fkTable1ID
    ) result1
group by result1.pkTable8ID,
    result1.Table8Val;
```

Comment: I can't stress enough not to use a query that produces a cartesian result set then hope the optimizer sorts it out for you. Especially when, in your case, its folding it four times. Given a non trivial amount of rows, I would be surprised if the query finished executing in a sort of reasonable amount of time.

Comment: My original query produced a result from a 119 column, 2.7M row dataset in 150s on a slow test server. Is this consistent with what you'd expect from such a misstep? Genuine curiosity, as I'd expect a cartesian product to take much longer to generate. Perhaps 2.7M rows is a small set, I don't have any frame of reference.

Comment: It would depend on your data. Its not a true caresian product of the entire table but each set of table1FK from Table2, Table3, Table4 and Table5. So if say Table1 had a row with primary key of 1 and it had 6 fks in table2, 4 in table3, 8 in table4 and 12 in table5 the result set would have 6 * 4 * 8 * 12 = 2304 rows.

Comment: As long as the FK counts are low the product would be low, so if the average was 1*2*1*2 = 4, for example, the result set before grouping would only be 4x bigger, not critical, but not optimal. If the result set was 2304x bigger, that would probably be critical.

Comment: While this does not solve my problem, which turns out to be caused by a faulty dataset as well, it does answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are too high, obviously you are duplicating values. First, you must reviewing your join fields, and then, be sure than your select is structured like this (or similar), depending on by which field you want to aggregate:

```
SELECT 
   t0.Table8Val, --or the field you want, remember put it in the group by too
   COUNT(t1.table1ID) as NumRows, --this 
   SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as WhatYouWant -- or this, or what you want to aggregate
FROM
    table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    table2 t2 
    ON t1.XX = t2.XX [AND t1.XX = t2.XX]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN   
    table3 t3
    ON t1.XX = t3.XX [AND t1.XX = t3.XX]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    table4 t4 
    ON t1.XX = t4.XX [AND t1.XX = t4.XX]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    table5 t5 
    ON t1.XX = t5.XX [AND t1.XX = t5.XX]
    (  SELECT
         t8.Table8Val, 
         COUNT(tx.field) as CountField, --these are examples
         SUM(tx.field)as SumField 
       FROM 
       table6 t6
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       table7 t7
       ON t6.XX = t7.XX [AND t6.XX = t7.XX]
       LEFT OUTER JOIN 
       table8 t8
       ON t6.XX = t8.XX [AND t6.XX = t8.XX]
       GROUP BY 
         t8.Table8Val )  t0
GROUP BY
  t0.Table8Val
```

Answer (score -3):

This works, i just coudlnt get sql fiddle to work, look slike "outer" joins would have solved your issues.

SELECT

```
    t8.Table8Val
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT t1.pkTable1ID) AS [Main]
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT t2.fkTable1ID) AS [Has t2 vals]
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT t3.fkTable1ID) AS [Has t3 vals]
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT t4.fkTable1ID) AS [Has t4 vals]
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT t5.fkTable1ID) AS [Has t5 vals]        

FROM            
    #Table8  t8  (NOLOCK)        
    inner JOIN        #Table7  t7  (NOLOCK)    ON  t8.pkTable8ID= t7.fkTable8ID
    inner JOIN        #Table6  t6  (NOLOCK)    ON  t7.pkTable7ID = t6.fkTable7ID
    LEFT outer JOIN   #Table1  t1  (NOLOCK)    ON  t1.pkTable1ID = t6.fkTable1ID
    LEFT outer JOIN   #Table2  t2  (NOLOCK)    ON  t1.pkTable1ID = t2.fkTable1ID                           
    LEFT outer JOIN   #Table3  t3  (NOLOCK)    ON  t1.pkTable1ID = t3.fkTable1ID                          
    LEFT outer JOIN   #Table4  t4  (NOLOCK)    ON  t1.pkTable1ID = t4.fkTable1ID  
    LEFT outer JOIN   #Table5  t5  (NOLOCK)    ON  t1.pkTable1ID = t5.fkTable1ID

WHERE
    t8.Table8Val IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY t8.Table8Val
```

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, aren't `JOIN` and `[LEFT|RIGHT] JOIN` just syntactic sugar for `INNER JOIN` and `[LEFT|RIGHT] OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: @Andy they are indeed.

Comment: @Andy worked for me , and yes they are. why you coudlnt get it to work on your end i dunno

Comment: @lookslikeanevo: To be fair, your "latest query" [does produce the desired output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/198df/2). (I had to tweak the schema, because you somehow made it for MySQL, and I also had to change the column names in your query because they were inconsistent with your schema, but that was all I changed.)

Comment: @AndyI didnt provide a sql fiddle so i coudlnt have used mysql - all tests i did were on ssms2008 r2